# Can't edit a code post, but can post one?

Tags: discussion, edits, code

This seems to be a problem to me. I have edited posts that have mostly or all code in them([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49457748/how-do-i-save-an-image-using-userdefaults-swift-xcode), for example), and I cannot edit the code alone because Stack Overflow says the edit is mostly code.

My question is: why can users post questions that are mostly code, but editors cannot edit the code of the post only?

**EDIT:** I have seen some "duplicates" of the question, but the OP of the question that I have linked formatted most of the code correctly, there was only one or two lines that weren't.

Comment: There are many duplicates, but the rule about "mostly code" was added after some questions were already asked.

Comment: Personally, I would let that question die rather than edit it. It's a horrible question...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan True, but I want to make some kind of effort to make it better...

Comment: You want to polish the turd? I don't think that's helpful. What's needed is for the OP to add what they are trying to do, the inputs provided, the output received and the outputs expected. Basically, a [mcve]. Unless you know what all of that is, I don't see how you're going to do any good here.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I can understand where XCoder is coming from. It's all new; enthusiasm runs high; one wants to contribute as well as use the new privileges... but experience and depth of knowledge about how the site is supposed to work aren't fully there. If priveleges are given "early" then a certain amount of learning how to use them is inevitable. But you can "be nice" about it. Instead of that last phrase which could well chase someone away, point the person to useful information in a meta post if you can't be bothered to spell it out.

Comment: @CindyMeister I certainly didn't intend to not "be nice". I understand he wants to be helpful, and I'm pointing out that editing that question is not helpful. I'm simply stating the facts. The lack of a coat of sugar does not mean the act of giving medicine is not nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you gain experience on Stack Overflow you'll begin to recognize what kinds of questions can be helped by editing, and what ones only the OP can salvage.

If a question needs more information, just cleaning up the code formatting won't help to make it more answerable. (Indeed, with some programming languages the faulty code formatting could be the reason for the problem, meaning you'd change the core of the question!) You're really only wasting your time - and the number of edits available to you for the day - that you could put to better use editing questions that can profit from your help.

Of course, the temptation to edit as many posts as possible, in order to gain badges, etc. is always there. But if you truly want to contribute to the quality of the site as well as help people with questions, step back and look at the question in its entirety: Is all the information there to make it possible to answer the question? If not,

- post a comment to the OP requesting additional information
- A link to the help center ( [help] ) about how to ask questions is usually in order in such cases
- At the same time, you can mention the code formatting if that's a
  problem.
- For people with low rep, always mention they should use
  the [edit] link to add the information directly into the question

When you edit, don't concentrate only on code. I review many suggested edits where someone has concentrated on visual formatting (in-line code, bold, etc.) and ignored glaring spelling and grammatical short-comings. Again, look at the entirety. Otherwise there's a good chance your edit will be rejected and the reviewer will make *all* the necessary corrections - you'll truly have wasted your time.

A very important kind of edit is bringing relevant information from the comments into the question, if the OP fails to do that. This can even be done after a question has been answered, as comments tend to be volatile.

One important point, from my point of view as a review queue reviewer, is to *never* try to edit a question that has been put on hold. That question gets **one** chance to be re-opened via the re-open queue, and performing an edit will automatically put it in that queue. But if the edit is just "cosmetic" then OP will have been robbed of the opportunity to substantially improve the question.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. I guess I'll take your advice.